# Is this a good place for beginners to seek information as they learn or is that type of discussion completely (or mostly) discouraged?

Tags: discussion, meta

Title says it all, and I don't have privileges to post on the meta forum. If there's a better place to post this, it'd be really helpful to hear about.

Comment: For a start http://academia.stackexchange.com/tour - discussions are discouraged as this is a question and answer site.

Comment: I suspect that you will not get a satisfying answer unless you specify what you mean with *beginners.*

Answer (score 6):

If the "beginner" questions are within the scope of the site as defined in the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and also are consistent with the general guidelines on [what not to ask](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) then yes, this is a good place for them.

Comment: We have quite a few questions from people who are obviously inexperienced when it comes to graduate studies, publishing, attending conferences and so forth.

Answer (score 5):

I am extremely confused by this question, but here goes.

> Is this a good place for beginners

Yes, definitely. I would say most of our questions are asked by relatively junior academics (assuming that this is what you mean with "beginners" - if you mean beginner in another sense, you should clarify).

> to seek information as they learn

Isn't that what most questions are about? Of course, as per Stack Exchange standard rules, you will need to do some basic research on the topic yourself first, the question needs to be generalizable to others, it needs to be in scope topic-wise, and it cannot be a duplicate of an existing question.

> or is that type of discussion completely (or mostly) discouraged?

*All* "discussions" are discouraged here. This isn't a forum. It is not supposed to be a back-and-forth between the OP and the community.